# Java - Printing ArrayList objects in specific format through toString() method

Tags: java, class, oop, arraylist

I'm making a solar system model that uses takes different solar systems and sets of planets through the use of classes. I've chosen to use an arraylist to store each object of a planet within the solar system although am now struggling to output the data in a suitable format.

The format i am looking for in the toString() method is 'Planet X has a mass of A Earths, is BAU from its star, and orbits in C years: could be habitable? D'

I have attempted using for loops to print each planet however don't believe this is the correct way as a return will cause the loop to stop. Many thanks

**SolarSystem.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SolarSystem {

    private String systemName;
    private double systemLuminosity;


    public SolarSystem(String name, double luminosity) {
        this.systemName = name;
        this.systemLuminosity = luminosity;
    }

    ArrayList<Planet> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance) {

        list.add(new Planet(name, mass, distance, systemLuminosity));

    }

    public void planetProperties() {

    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(list.size());
        String results = "+";
        for (Planet planet : list) {
            results += planet.getName(); //if you implement toString() for Dog then it will be added here
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

**Planet.java**

```
    public class Planet {

        private String planetName;
        private double planetMass;
        private double distanceFromStar;
        private double orbitalPeriod;
        private String isHabitable;

        public Planet(String name, double mass, double distance, double systemLuminosity) {

            setName(name);
            setMass(mass);
            setDistanceFromSun(distance);
            setOrbitalPeriod(distance);
            setIsHabitable(mass, distance, systemLuminosity);


        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            planetName = name;
        }

        public  String getName() {
            return planetName;
        }

        public  void setMass(double mass) {
            planetMass = mass;
        }

        public double getMass() {
            return planetMass;
        }

        public void setDistanceFromSun(double distance) {
            distanceFromStar = distance;
        }

        public double getDistanceFromStar() {
            return distanceFromStar;
        }

        public void setOrbitalPeriod(double distance) {
            orbitalPeriod = Math.sqrt(distance*distance*distance);
        }

        public double getOrbitalPeriod() {
            return orbitalPeriod;
        }

        public void setIsHabitable(double mass, double distance, double luminosity) {
            if (mass >= 0.6 && mass <= 7.0) {
                if ((distance >= 0.75 * Math.sqrt(luminosity)) && (distance <= 2.0 * Math.sqrt(luminosity))) {
                    isHabitable = "yes";
                } else {
                    isHabitable = "no";
                }
            } else {
                isHabitable = "no";
            }

        }

        public String getIsHabitable() {
            return isHabitable;
        }
    }
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create our solar system
        SolarSystem ourSystem = new SolarSystem("Our System",1.0);

        //Add planets in our solar system
        ourSystem.addPlanet("Mercury", 0.055, 0.387);
        ourSystem.addPlanet("Venus", 0.815, 0.723);
        ourSystem.addPlanet("Earth", 1.0, 1.0);
        ourSystem.addPlanet("Mars", 0.107, 1.52);
        ourSystem.addPlanet("Jupiter", 317.8, 5.20);
        ourSystem.addPlanet("Saturn", 95.2, 9.58);
        ourSystem.addPlanet("Uranus", 14.5, 19.20);
        ourSystem.addPlanet("Neptune", 17.1, 30.05);

        System.out.println(ourSystem.toString());



    }
}
```

Comment: Is that you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720304/cant-make-program-change-object-inside-arraylist?

Comment: If thats how you want to display the information of the planets you just need to add a `.toString()` method in your Planet class and change the `results += planet.getName();` line for `results += planet.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `toString()` method inside your `Planet` class, for example:

```
class Planet {
    private String planetName;
    private double planetMass;
    private double distanceFromStar;
    private double orbitalPeriod;
    private String isHabitable;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Planet %s has a mass of %f Earths, is %f from its star, and orbits in %f years: could be habitable? %s%n",
                this.planetName, this.planetMass, this.distanceFromStar, this.orbitalPeriod, this.isHabitable);
    }

}
```

Then inside your `SolarSystem` class you can create a list with something like this, you already have that part almost correct but I've changed `getName` to `toString`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for (Planet planet : list) {
        buf.append(planet);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: What about planetMass? It's not number of Earth masses

Comment: @RafałSokalski The values entered are the number of Earth masses [source](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/planet_table_ratio.html)

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Fair enough, I've fixed it, that was his original code which was slightly altered though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out a description for the entire solar system (the entire array list of planets), I would suggest to implement the toString() method inside the Planet class. Doing so will allow you to simply iterate over the Planets array list, and just call planet.toString(). Encapsulating the logic for a singular planet inside the Planet class is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redefine `toString` in the `Planet` class and replace the `toString` of `SolarSystem` to use it.

```
public class Planet {
  ...
  public String toString() {
     return "Planet " + planetName + " has a mass of " + planetMass + 
            " Earths, is BAU from its star, and orbits in " + orbitalPeriod + 
            " years: could be habitable? " + isHabitable;
  }
}

public class SolarSystem {
  ...

  public String toString() {
    String results = "";
     for (Planet planet : list) {
        results += planet.toString() + "\n"; // Use the toString of planet and add a new line 
     }
     return results;
  }
}
```

Note: for performance reasons as commented by oleg it is preferable to use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings. In this situation where you have few items and the problem is not related to the performances you can leave the + operator.

---

Growing your java knowledge you will find useful functions like [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-):

> Returns a new String composed of copies of the CharSequence elements joined together with a copy of the specified delimiter.

That will help you mantaining your code simpler and cleaner replacing this:

```
public String toString() {
    String results = "";
     for (Planet planet : list) {
        results += planet.toString() + "\n"; // Use the toString of planet and add a new line 
     }
     return results;
  }
```

with

```
public String toString() {
  return String.join("\n", list);
}
```

but my tip is to start from the basis of java before trying to use more advanced functions. Otherwise you will use them without knowing what happens behind the scenes

Comment: @oleg.cherednik This is an example. It can be accomplished with a StringBuilder but it add complexity to the readibility and is out of scope for this example

Comment: Anyway, this is bad practice and should not be done. This guy probably does not know about this and copy past your solution.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik and this is ok for the first exercises. You can't introduce performance aspects if you don't know how toString works. Mantaining the solution as simple as possible is a good quality to mantain the focus on the objective of the example that is using toString

Answer (score 0):

To echo other posters, you need to define a custom toString() method in the planet class first. Please see my suggestions below. They are presented as pseudo-code typed on the fly, not actual code (for there might be a few things here and there that might not compile.)

But the pseudo-code should give an idea for a possible solution. Hit me up if you still have questions.

Based on your requirements:

> The format i am looking for in the toString() method is 'Planet X has
>   a mass of A Earths, is BAU from its star, and orbits in C years: could
>   be habitable? D'

Your Planet.toString method *could* look as follows (this is pseudo-code, not bound to be compilable, but you get the gist of it.)

```
public class Planet {

    /* your class as it is, with the 
     * addition of a possible toString 
     * implementation */

        public String toString(){
                return String.format(
                    "Planet: %s, " + 
                    "mass: %f, " + 
                    "distance: %f, " + 
                    "orbital period: %f, " + 
                    "habitable: %b" 
                    this.getName(), 
                    this.getMass(), 
                    this.getDistanceFromStar(), 
                    this.getOrbitalPeriod(),
                    this.getIsHabitable());
        }
}
```

Then, your SolarSystem class should have an appropriate toString method that loops over the collection of planets in it. Your original toString method had the right idea, I'm just extending the notion.

```
public class SolarSystem {

    /* 
    Your solar system class plus some changes 

    ... 
    */

    public String getName(){
        return this.systemName;
    }

    public String getLuminosity(){
        return this.systemLuminosity;
    }

    public int getPlanetCount(){
        return this.list.size();
    }

    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append(
            String.format("System: %s\nLuminosity: %f\nPlanet Count:%d\n",
                this.getName(),
                this.getLuminosity(),
                this.getPlanetCount()
            )
        );
        for (final Planet planet : list) {
            buffer.append('\t')
                .append(planet.getString())
                .append('\n');
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

}
```

Now, I'm a bit confused with this:

> I have attempted using for loops to print each planet however don't
>   believe this is the correct way as a return will cause the loop to
>   stop. Many thanks

A return statement will stop a loop if the return is done within the loop.

A return statement done within a function called within the loop *will not* end the loop.

That is, a return only ends the function that makes the return call, not functions up in the call chain.

Compare this

```
for(Foo f : fooList){
  if(something){ 
    return; // this will stop the loop
  }
}
```

With this

```
for(Foo f : fooList){
   if(something){
      callThisFu(); // the return within callThisFu *will not* exit the loop
   }
}
```

Hope this clear this up.